# Unable to fetch specific content from tweets using scala on spark shell

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am working on Hortonworks.I have stored tweets from twitter to Kafka topic.I am performing sentiment analysis on tweets using Kafka as a Producer and Spark as a Consumer using Scala on Spark-shell.But I want to fetch only specific content from tweets like Text,HashTag,tweets is positive or negative,words from the tweets which i selected as a positive or negative word.my training data is Data.txt.

I added dependencies : 
org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.2,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.10:1.6.2

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds 
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._

val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("KafkaReceiver")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))
val zkQuorum="sandbox.hortonworks.com:2181"
val group="test-consumer-group"
val topics="test"
val numThreads=5
val args=Array(zkQuorum, group, topics, numThreads)
val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap).map(_._2)
val hashTags = lines.flatMap(_.split(" ")).filter(_.startsWith("#"))
val wordSentimentFilePath = "hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/TwitterData/Data.txt"
val wordSentiments = ssc.sparkContext.textFile(wordSentimentFilePath).map { line =>
      val Array(word, happiness) = line.split("\t")
      (word, happiness)
    } cache()
    val happiest60 = hashTags.map(hashTag => (hashTag.tail, 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(60)).transform{topicCount => wordSentiments.join(topicCount)}.map{case (topic, tuple) => (topic, tuple._1 * tuple._2)}.map{case (topic, happinessValue) => (happinessValue, topic)}.transform(_.sortByKey(false))
happiest60.print()
ssc.start()
```

I got the output like this,

(negative,fear)
(positive,fitness)

I want output like this,

(#sports,Text from the Tweets,fitness,positive)

But I am not getting the solution to store Text and Hashtag like above.

Comment: Can you add  "TwitterData/Data.txt" sample data also in question

Comment: Data.txt contain words and posititve,negative word which is seperated by Tab....
[like positive
doom negative
doomed negative
doubt positive
doubted positive
doubtful positive
doubting positive
doubts positive
douche positive
douchebag positive]